# 'Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette' when colours are already stated

Tags: r, colors

I am trying to plot two lines from different datasets and this code has worked perfectly for me previously but when I run it now I get this error:

Error: Must request at least one colour from a hue palette.

My dataset contains three variables, species, CO2 and SD (stomatal density). I'm attempting to plot change in SD over CO2.

Here's my code

```
lab<- read.csv("lab.csv", header = TRUE)
review <- read.csv("review.csv", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_minimal())


ggplot(data = lab, aes(x = CO2, y =SD)) +
  geom_point(data=lab, colour = "Black") +
  geom_smooth(fill = NA, colour = "Black") +
 geom_smooth(data=review, aes(x=CO2, y=SD, fill=NA, colour="Blue")) + 
 geom_point(data=review, colour = "Blue")
```

Here's my data

```
dput(lab)
dput(review)
```

structure(list(ï..Species = c("Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens"),  SD = c(358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87, 358.87,
358.87, 358.87, 361.2, 361.2, 361.2, 361.2, 361.2, 363.55,
363.55, 363.55, 363.55, 337.86, 373.47, 373.47, 373.47, 373.47,
387.63, 389.63, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27,
392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27,
392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 392.27, 393.83, 411.11, 411.11,
356.46, 356.46, 358.87, 361.2, 353.83, 387.63, 389.63, 393.83,
409.39, 411.18), CO2 = c(60, 108.1, 135.6, 128.4, 115.1,
202.6, 102.4, 65.9, 39.3, 45, 79.5, 105.2, 93.9, 75.3, 79.3,
62, 93.9, 81.4, 101, 66.8, 132.81, 132.81, 92.45, 174.6,
160, 243.68, 187.98, 229.76, 222.76, 208.87, 160.13, 194.95,
215.83, 222.79, 201.91, 208.87, 187.98, 250.64, 181.02, 292.42,
264.57, 257.61, 264.57, 243.68, 14, 127, 143, 147, 61, 87.8,
65, 124.5, 111.1, 107, 12.6, 2.99, 2.99)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-57L))

structure(list(ï..Species = c("Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens",
"Betula pubescens", "Betula pubescens"), SD = c(118.02, 108.07,
104.69, 97.94, 94.56, 91.19, 91.19, 87.81, 84.43, 70.92, 131.71,
128.34, 108.07, 108.07, 104.69, 94.56, 94.56, 87.81, 87.81, 77.68,
74.3, 74.3, 70.92, 70.92, 67.54, 60.79, 57.41, 57.41, 54.04,
50.66, 81.05, 81.05, 77.68, 77.68, 74.3, 67.54, 67.54, 60.79,
54.04, 54.04, 81.05, 77.68, 70.92, 70.92, 67.45, 64.17, 64.17,
57.41, 57.41, 54.04, 104.69, 91.19, 84.43, 74.3, 74.3, 67.45,
67.45, 64.17, 57.41, 50.66, 70.92, 67.45, 64.17, 64.17, 60.79,
60.79, 60.79, 60.79, 60.79, 57.41, 57.41, 57.41, 54.03, 54.03,
54.03, 54.03, 50.66, 47.28, 47.28, 43.9, 94.56, 87.81, 81.05,
74.3, 70.92, 70.92, 67.45, 67.45, 60.79, 50.66, 84.43, 74.3,
74.3, 70.92, 70.92, 64.17, 60.79, 60.79, 60.79, 57.41, 57.41,
54.03, 54.03, 54.03, 50.66, 50.66, 47.28, 40.53, 40.53, 37.15,
87.81, 70.92, 67.45, 64.17, 60.79, 60.79, 60.79, 57.41, 57.41,
57.41, 57.41, 54.04, 54.03, 54.03, 54.03, 50.66, 43.9, 40.53,
40.53, 30.4, 57.41, 50.66, 47.28, 47.28, 47.28, 47.28, 40.53,
40.53, 37.15, 33.77, 60.79, 47.28, 47.28, 43.9, 30.4, 30.4, 27.02,
23.64, 23.64, 20.26, 114.83, 97.94, 94.56, 74.3, 74.29, 70.92,
70.92, 60.79, 43.9, 11.45, 60.79, 57.41, 57.41, 54.04, 54.04,
54.04, 50.66, 50.66, 50.66, 50.66, 47.28, 47.28, 43.9, 37.15,
33.77, 33.77, 23.64, 23.64, 20.26, 16.89, 74.3, 54.04, 50.66,
47.28, 47.28, 47.28, 43.9, 43.9, 43.9, 43.9, 43.9, 40.53, 40.53,
37.15, 37.15, 37.15, 33.77, 33.77, 27.02, 23.64, 60.79, 54.04,
50.66, 47.28, 47.28, 47.28, 43.9, 43.9, 43.9, 40.53, 40.53, 40.53,
40.53, 37.15, 33.77, 33.77, 33.77, 33.77, 27.02, 16.89, 54.04,
47.28, 40.53, 33.77, 33.77, 33.77, 27.02, 27.02, 27.02, 23.64,
50.66, 43.9, 43.9, 43.9, 40.53, 37.15, 37.15, 27.02, 16.89, 16.89,
50.66, 40.53, 33.77, 33.77, 33.77, 30.4, 27.02, 27.02, 27.02,
23.64, 40.53, 40.53, 37.15, 37.15, 33.77, 30.4, 27.02, 27.02,
20.26, 16.89), CO2 = c(293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293, 293,
293, 293, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295,
295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295,
295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295, 295,
295, 295, 295, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297, 297,
297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5,
297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5, 297.5,
297.5, 297.5, 298.5, 298.5, 298.5, 298.5, 298.5, 298.5, 298.5,
298.5, 298.5, 298.5, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300,
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 309,
309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309,
309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 311, 311, 311, 311, 311, 311, 311,
311, 311, 311, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314, 314,
317.64, 317.64, 317.64, 317.64, 317.64, 317.64, 317.64, 317.64,
317.64, 317.64, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84,
325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84,
325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 325.84, 331.12, 331.12,
331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12,
331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12, 331.12,
331.12, 331.12, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84,
333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84,
333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 333.84, 336.84, 336.84,
336.84, 336.84, 336.84, 336.84, 336.84, 336.84, 336.84, 336.84,
343.15, 343.15, 343.15, 343.15, 343.15, 343.15, 343.15, 343.15,
343.15, 343.15, 344.85, 344.85, 344.85, 344.85, 344.85, 344.85,
344.85, 344.85, 344.85, 344.85, 394.06, 394.06, 394.06, 394.06,
394.06, 394.06, 394.06, 394.06, 394.06, 394.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-260L))

Would anyone be able to help me with this error? I've stated the colours for each set of lines and points and this code has worked for me in the past so I'm unsure what the issue is. I've also checked previous questions of the same error code on this website but the issues were either that the colours hadn't been assigned or there was missing data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting fill in the aesthetic in the fourth line of your code is causing the error, because it should actually be outside. If you want to get rid of the shading and make the smoothing line blue, you could accomplish that via the following:

```
ggplot(data = lab, aes(x = CO2, y =SD)) +
  geom_point(data=lab, colour = "Black") +
  geom_smooth(fill = NA, colour = "Black") +
  geom_smooth(data=review, aes(x=CO2, y=SD), fill = NA, colour = "Blue") + 
  geom_point(data=review, colour = "Blue")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help once again @Carey Caginalp, this solved the problem for me. I truly appreciate all your time and expertise.